# Can we force monotonicity for a subset of features in h2o gbms?

Tags: boosting, h2o

I was wondering if it's possible to force variables to be monotonic when building gbms in h2o? Ideally this would be enforced globally, although even the standard local constraint would be better than nothing.

(example of my view of a local constraint : say that we want a variable x to be monotonically increasing -> if a tree is set to split using x but the resulting left average would be less than the resulting right average, then we don't make the split and move on to the next best candidate. Forcing monotonicity globally would be more involved - I only have a rough idea of how to do this and it could dramatically slow down the algorithm.)

Thanks,
Tom

Comment: Do you know of another GBM implementation that does this? (Or a link to a paper describing the technique and motivation?)

Comment: Hi Darren, the gbm package in R supports local monotonicity. I'm not aware of any implementation of a global constraint (I think it would be quite messy, as you'd probably need to stop growing a tree past any node that had  a monotonicity constraint imposed on it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Monotonicity constraints are [supported](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/1514) in XGBoost ([Python example here](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/monotonic.html)), and H2O will expose this in the H2O XGBoost GBM function (follow progress of this feature [here](https://0xdata.atlassian.net/browse/PUBDEV-5271)).  However, there is not currently a way to do this using the native H2O GBM implementation.